Как я могу сбросить состояние второму пользователю в Telegram боте?
Я делаю игру, где два человека могут подключиться в лобби и играть друг против друга, когда они начинают игру, то у них устанавливается состояние Game.start.
Если какой-то пользователь Отменит игру то она у него отменится (await state.clear()) и состояние отчистится, но как отчистить и второму пользователю?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
